# Symmetry Protected Topological (SPT) phases of spin-1 chains

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-order, topological-phase

Let's consider this family of 1D spin-1 of hamiltonians:

$$\sum_{i}[S^x_{i}S^{x}_{i+1}+S^y_{i}S^{y}_{i+1}+\lambda S^z_{i}S^{z}_{i+1} + D(S^{z}_{i})^2].$$

If I understand it right, these models have:

1. Translational symmetry
2. Inversion symmetry ($S^{x,y,z}_{i}\to S^{x,y,z}_{-i+1}$)
3. Time reversal symmetry ($S^{x,y,z}_{i}\to - S^{x,y,z}_{i}$)
4. $Z_2\times Z_2$ symmetry ($\pi$-rotation about $x, y $ anz $z$ axes $S^{\alpha,\beta}_{i}\to - S^{\alpha,\beta}_{i},
       S^{\gamma}_{i}\to S^{\gamma}_{i}$).

Then according to [1] there should be 1024 different SPT phases. But other than the Haldane phase and the trivial topological phase I don't know any other topological phase for this class of hamiltonians [2]. Where are the other phases?

References:

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.3323

[2] Kennedy, T. & Tasaki, H. Commun.Math. Phys. (1992) 147: 431. https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02097239

Comment: 1024, lovely. This model only realizes two SPT phases: the archetypal Haldane phase ($\lambda =0$; $D=0$) and the trivial phase ($D \to \infty$) (as well as a symmetry-breaking phase for $\lambda \to \infty$). For the other 1022 phases, you need other lattice models. There are papers on this as well, in particular by Wen. However, I haven't really seen physically plausible models that realize those other phases.

Comment: In fact, scratch that: this nice paper shows that a physically reasonable spin-$2$ model realizes a variety of SPT phases with your above symmetry groups: https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.3370